# How do I fix when Eclipse show list of open files displays white text on white background in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu, gnome

[image]

As you can see the non highlighted file names are invisbile.

This is on Ubuntu 20.04. It was working fine on Ubuntu 16.04. Recently jumped from 16->18->20.04.

It is the default Gnome desktop.

What options do I need to change to alter the color of the Show List (>>)

Answer (score 0):

So one solution was to install gnome-tweaks and then select
Themes Applications - HighContrastInverse

Yaru dark was just unusable - grey on black is not a good contrast.